# Параметры width="" height="" в Bootstrap для SEO

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, seo

Обязательно ли прописывать для каждой картинки параметры "width" и "height" в html-коде страницы, для лучшего SEO-продвижения сайта?

Comment: Да, ну например если будут искать картинку с вашим размером в поисковике картинок.

Comment: SEO - это поисковая оптимизация и это ваш выбор, там нет обязаловки. Поэтому, указание параметров ширины и высоты, для картинок необязательны. Большую роль в оптимизации картинок играет описание картинок в alt. Возможно вам помогут эти статьи о респонсивных изображениях https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/images?hl=ru ++ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images ++ https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp